# Pandas, create MultIndex column from a column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

[image]

Suppose I have a data frame like this. The index of this dataframe is a MultiIndex alredy, date/id.
Column N tells the price information is N periods before. How could I turn column['N'] into a MultiIndex?

In this example, suppose columns N has two unique value [0, 1], the final result would have 6 columns and it should look like [0/priceClose] [0/priceLocal]  [0/priceUSD] [1/priceClose] [1/priceLocal]  [1/priceUSD]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the following method works:

step 1: melt

step 2: pivot

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['date', 'id', 'N'], 
                 value_vars=[p for p in df if p.startswith('price')], 
                 value_name='price')

df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='price', index=['date', 'id'],
                    columns=['variable', 'N'], aggfunc='max')
```